# case sensitive in android

Tags: android

Is there a piece of code that is added, when I want to make my program case insensitive? Examples of word search program that is not case sensitive. Example of such a link below

[www.agusharyanto.net/wordpress/?p=317](http://www.agusharyanto.net/wordpress/?p=317)

Answer (score 0):

No, you should use such functions as toUpperCase() or toLowerCase() comparing Strings. Of course, using these, you can provide such service to your user.

**Edit:** Oh, I found one more function equalsIgnoreCase():

Example:

```
    String ss = "hello";
    String SS = "HELLO";

    boolean a1 = ss.toLowerCase().equals(SS.toLowerCase());
    boolean a2 = ss.toUpperCase().equals(SS.toUpperCase());
    boolean a3 = ss.equalsIgnoreCase(SS);
```

All a1,a2,a3 will be true. These comparison are working in default locale (in user's language). toUpperCase() or toLowerCase() have variants: toUpperCase(Locale) or toLowerCase(Locale). Using these you can transform cases in locales other, than default. equalsIgnoreCase  has not such convenience.

Comment: Could you give examples of programs that you explain?